# Refresh token (JWT) in interceptor Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, rxjs6

Initially, I had a function that simply checked for the presence of a token and, if it was not present, sent the user to the login header. Now I need to implement the logic of refreshing a token when it expires with the help of a refreshing token. But I get an error 401. The refresh function does not have time to work and the work in the interceptor goes further to the error. How can I fix the code so that I can wait for the refresh to finish, get a new token and not redirect to the login page?

**TokenInterceptor**

```
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable, Injector} from "@angular/core";
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import {Observable, throwError} from "rxjs";
import {catchError, tap} from "rxjs/operators";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {JwtHelperService} from "@auth0/angular-jwt";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

  private auth: AuthService;

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {}

  jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);

    const accToken = this.auth.getToken();
    const refToken = this.auth.getRefreshToken();

    if ( accToken && refToken ) {

      if ( this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(accToken) ) {
        this.auth.refreshTokens().pipe(
          tap(
            () => {
              req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${accToken}`
                }
              });
            }
          )
        )
      } else {
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accToken}`
          }
        });
      }

    }
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleAuthError(error)
      )
    );
  }

  private handleAuthError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any>{
    if (error.status === 401) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
        queryParams: {
          sessionFailed: true
        }
      });
    }
    return throwError(error);
  }

}
```

**AuthService**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import {RefreshTokens, Tokens, User} from "../interfaces";
import {map, tap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService{

  private authToken = null;
  private refreshToken = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  setToken(authToken: string) {
    this.authToken = authToken;
  }

  setRefreshToken(refreshToken: string) {
    this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
  }

  getToken(): string {
    this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    return this.authToken;
  };

  getRefreshToken(): string {
    this.refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh-token');
    return this.refreshToken;
  };

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.authToken;
  }

  isRefreshToken(): boolean {
    return !!this.refreshToken;
  }

  refreshTokens(): Observable<any> {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getRefreshToken()
      })
    };

    return this.http.post<RefreshTokens>('/api2/auth/refresh', {}, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap((tokens: RefreshTokens) => {
          localStorage.setItem('auth-token', tokens.access_token);
          localStorage.setItem('refresh-token', tokens.refresh_token);
          this.setToken(tokens.access_token);
          this.setRefreshToken(tokens.refresh_token);
          console.log('Refresh token ok');
        })
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: if the token is already expired your backend send 401 to you. you need to refresh before the token expires

Comment: or you can extend token's expiration date for each received request

Comment: is your problem get fixed can you help with answer how you did it

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like that:

```
const firstReq = cloneAndAddHeaders(req);

return next.handle(firstReq).pipe(
   catchError(
      err => {
         if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
               if (firstReq.url === '/api2/auth/refresh') {
                  auth.setToken('');
                  auth.setRefreshToken('');
                  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
               } else {
                  return this.auth.refreshTokens()
                    .pipe(mergeMap(() => next.handle(cloneAndAddHeaders(req))));
               }
            }
            return throwError(err.message || 'Server error');
         }
      }
    )
 );
```

The implementation of `cloneAndAddHeaders` should be something like this:

```
private cloneAndAddHeaders(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({
       setHeaders: {
           Authorization: `YourToken`
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you never subscribe to your `refreshTokens().pipe()` code. Without a subscription, the observable won't execute.

Comment: If I do in TokenInterceptor `this.auth.refreshTokens().subscribe(...)`, it goes into an infinite loop, returning an error at each iteration.

Comment: Sounds like a different code flow problem, but in a microcosm, I still stand by the need to `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
req = this.auth.refreshTokens().pipe(
      switchMap(() => req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
            }
          }))
      )
```

This will first call `refreshToken` and run the `tap` there, then emit request with the new `this.auth.getToken()`, note that `accToken` still have old value as the code is not rerun.